# Unable to introduce password in jupyter notebook

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook

I am running Jupyter notebook in a remote server. Once I am inside of the remote server I need to run '!ssh namemachine' to enter in the computer with GPU. This command ask me for a password, so, my problem is that I cannot enter any password since Jupyter does not allow me to do it.
I have try with yes command, and !ssh namemachine -password. I have been looking for days and I am not able to figure out how to enter the password.
I really appreciate any kind of help! :)